# Do I need private key each time when call smart contract?

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs

I am using `web3` library to connect to smart contracts deployed in Ganache/Ethereum network. I don't need to sign a transaction when interacting with Ganache network probably because it is a test environment doesn't require signing. The code is:

```
      await contract.methods
                .createSector(
                  
                  { value: web3.utils.fromWei(price, 'ether') }
                ).send({from: address});
```

However, I get `unknown account` error if I call contract from Sepolia test network. I have to sign the transaction as below:

```
const w = new Web3(url);
      await w.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
            {
              from: account.address,
              to: contractAddress,
              gas: 1000000,
              gasPrice: 1000000000,
              nonce: await w.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address),
              data: await contract.methods
                .createSector(
                  
                  { value: web3.utils.fromWei(price, 'ether') }
                )
                .encodeABI(),
            },
            privateKey
          );
```

You can see that I need to provide `privateKey` otherwise I will get `unknown account` error. I wonder if it is the right way to implement that. Put `private key` in frontend code is not secure which I'd like to avoid. Is there a better way to do the job?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No

Try this: https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/eth_call

eth_call: `Executes a new message call immediately without creating a transaction on the block chain`

If you don't create a transaction, you don't need privatekey. Some wallets have a feature that allow you to import a wallet as `readonly`, all you need is just an address, not privatekey